# SSO google sign-in Couldn't sign

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-sso

We are developing a react-native web assets app (for iOS & android patform). Which has SSO integration, When I press google login button. I will redirect to google sign-in page, after entered the mail-id, which is not taking me to password entering screen. I'm getting Couldn't sign you in (below error message in the screenshot).

[image]